# Chrome extension using devtool for Har file save

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So here is what I am trying to do.
I want to save all the HTTP (content+request+response) while I am using google chrome. I found a way to this using network tool (in developer tool), where I can download everything manually.

Now I want to automate this whole process so I don't need to do any manual thing. I thought we can do this by writing a simple Chrome Extension using `devtools.network` API.

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
    function(request) {
    //dosomething
});
```

But I am kind lost here I never did the Chrome Extension development before. I made a simple `manifest.json` file:

```
{
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "My extension",
     "version" : "1.0",
     "background": {
         "scripts": ["devtools.js"],
         "persistent": true
     },
     "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
     "browser_action": {
         "default_title": "Get it",
         "default_icon" : "icon.png"
     }
}
```

and pasted the first code snippet in `devtools.js`, but it is giving me an error:

> network not defined

Am I on the right track? If so, what I am doing wrong with my code?

Comment: "Is giving me errors" is not a good description.

Comment: when I try to load the extension it says: network not defined. can you please tell me where I should add this line exactly chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener()

Answer (score 4):

From ["Extending DevTools"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools):

> The `chrome.devtools.*` API modules are available only to the pages loaded within the DevTools window. Content scripts and other extension pages do not have these APIs. Thus, the APIs are available only through the lifetime of the DevTools window.

So you can use this in `devtools.html` as long as it's opened, but not in background.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger), which works as long as Dev Tools <del>are *not* opened</del>. Do note it's a pretty low-level API with little documentation.

Since, judging from your other questions, your goal is to automate the process - it's probably a better path (since there is no automated way to open a page with Dev Tools enabled as far as I know). The `debugger` API can replicate what Dev Tools do, <del>but only one tool can be attached to a page at a time - for that reason, `debugger` stops working if Dev Tools are invoked</del>.

**EDIT:** since Chrome 63 multiple debugger clients are supported by Chrome, making it possible to attach both Dev Tools and `chrome.debugger` at the same time.

Comment: Hi can you please elaborate what do you mean by devTool window? Like it will only work if I have opened the dev tool option and load the page in an other window. If so I am okay with this

Comment: Read the article linked at the top. Any visible page can have a Dev Tools window attached to it. Your page, `devtools.html`, will be embedded there as a tab. You can only use the API in that page, and it will only collect events while Dev Tools are open.

Comment: @Xan we can use debugger to capture HAR also?